# Do I need to file taxes in the city I work?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ohio

I live and work in Ohio. However, I moved in 2016 to a village without city income tax. However, I work in a city with income taxes. I started with this organization in 2017.

My employer has been deducting the work city taxes since I started. Should I be paying those taxes? Wouldn't they normally be transferred to the city that I owed income tax to? So, if that tax is less or 0% should it be refunded to me?

If so, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: when did you start? 2017 or 2018?

Comment: I edited to include 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have the option to file individual municipal tax returns through the joint federal and state Modernized e-File (MeF) program. Here is the process:

> A taxpayer may elect to file on a centralized basis by the first day of the third month after the beginning of the taxpayer's taxable year (March 1 for calendar year taxpayers). The ability to elect to file on a centralized basis has been available since October 2017 and is available at www.tax.ohio.gov/MunicipalTax.aspx or by filing Form MNP R. In February 2018, it is anticipated that a taxpayer will be able to make the election via the Ohio Business Gateway (OBG). Once the election has been made by the electing taxpayer, it automatically renews year to year unless an electing taxpayer terminates the election by filing a form with the tax commissioner by the first day of the third month of any taxable year. There is no fee to the taxpayer to make an election and to participate in the centralized municipal tax system.

**References**

- [Centralized collection of the Ohio municipal net profit tax is here](https://www.ohiocpa.com/search/utilities/displaynewsitem/2018/01/24/centralized-collection-of-the-ohio-municipal-net-profit-tax-is-here)
- [Central Collection Agency (CCA)](http://ccatax.ci.cleveland.oh.us/?p=ccamap)
- [Regional Income Tax Authority](http://www.ritaohio.com/Municipalities)